# How to use buttons to type in a text field?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, keyboard, awt

In a program I'm attempting to make, there are three text field accompanied by several buttons (each representing a number). I'm trying to get it so you can type by clicking on the buttons (as opposed to the keyboard). So far, I got this:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.text.*;

public class GUI extends JFrame {

    private JButton[] numPad = new JButton[10];
    private JTextField totalBill = new JTextField();
    private JTextField totalPeople = new JTextField();
    private JTextField tipPercentage = new JTextField();
    private JTextField tipAmount = new JTextField();
    private JTextField grandTotal = new JTextField();
    private JTextField totalPerPerson = new JTextField();
    private JButton doneButton = new JButton("Done");
    private JButton clearButton = new JButton("Clear");
    ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    private JPanel superContainer;
    private JPanel container;
    private JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
    private JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();

    public GUI() {

            //Set JFrame title.
            super("Tip Calculator");

            superContainer = new JPanel();
            superContainer.setLayout(new BoxLayout(superContainer, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    //Create a container to hold two GridLayouts beside one another.
            container = new JPanel();
            container.setLayout(new BoxLayout(container, BoxLayout.X_AXIS));

    //Create panels to be placed in container panel.
            panel1.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 250));
            panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(4,3,10,10));
            panel2.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(500, 250));
            panel2.setLayout(new GridLayout(7,2,10,10));

            //Populate all the JButtons for the numPad.
            for (int i=0; i<=9; i++) {
                numPad[i] = new JButton(Integer.toString(i));
            }

            //Place each numPad button on the first JPanel.
            for (int i=1; i<=9; i++) {
                panel1.add(numPad[i]);
            }
            panel1.add(numPad[0]);

            //Populate second GridLayout.
            panel2.add(new JLabel("Total Bill: "));
            panel2.add(totalBill);
            panel2.add(new JLabel("Total People: "));
            panel2.add(totalPeople);
            panel2.add(new JLabel("Total Percentage: "));
            panel2.add(tipPercentage);
            panel2.add(doneButton);
            panel2.add(clearButton);
            panel2.add(new JLabel("Tip Amount: "));
            panel2.add(tipAmount);
            panel2.add(new JLabel("Grand Total: "));
            panel2.add(grandTotal);
            panel2.add(new JLabel("Total/Person: "));
            panel2.add(totalPerPerson);
            grandTotal.setEditable(false);
            tipAmount.setEditable(false);
            totalPerPerson.setEditable(false);


            //Add the first GridLayout panel to the container.
            container.add(panel1);
            //Create a space between the GridLayout panels.
            container.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(30,0)));
            //Add the second GridLayout panel to the container.
            container.add(panel2);

            //Same as above but with title ontop and container panel below.
            superContainer.add(new JLabel("Title"));
            superContainer.add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0,30)));
            superContainer.add(container);

            //The panel the JFrame uses.
            this.setContentPane(superContainer);

            TheHandler handler = new TheHandler();
            doneButton.addActionListener(handler);
            clearButton.addActionListener(handler);

    }

    private class TheHandler implements ActionListener {

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

                   if (e.getSource()==doneButton) {
                            tipAmount.setText(Double.toString(Double.parseDouble(totalBill.getText()) * (Double.parseDouble(tipPercentage.getText()) / 100)));
                            grandTotal.setText(Double.toString(Double.parseDouble(tipAmount.getText()) + Double.parseDouble(totalBill.getText())));
                            totalPerPerson.setText(Double.toString(Double.parseDouble(grandTotal.getText()) / Double.parseDouble(totalPeople.getText()))); }
                    else if (e.getSource()==clearButton) {
                            grandTotal.setText("");
                            tipAmount.setText("");
                            totalPerPerson.setText("");
                            totalBill.setText("0");
                            tipPercentage.setText("0");
                            totalPeople.setText("1");
                            totalBill.requestFocus();
                            totalBill.selectAll(); }

            }


    }

}
```

After searching the Internet, I came across the following code:

```
    private class AddDigit extends TextAction {
        private String digit;

        public AddDigit(String digit) {

            super( digit );
            this.digit = digit;

        }

        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

            JTextComponent component = getFocusedComponent();
            component.replaceSelection( digit );

        }

    }
```

The only problem is, I have no clue how to use the code I found (the code I found being the second block).

[Where I got the code from.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763695/add-text-to-a-text-field-via-jbuttons-when-there-are-two-textfields-calculator?rq=1)

Comment: So, instead of the user entering a value into the field manually, they can "click" the num pad?  Or do you want the number pad to act like the keyboard num pad, as they type a number it triggers the corresponding button?

Comment: @Reimeus That first block of code is my code. I'm just curious on how to get the second block working with the first.

Comment: @MadProgrammer So they can click the numpad (with the keyboard still functional tho).

Comment: If they use is never expected to interact with this virtual keypad, I would simply make the buttons un-focusable

Comment: @MadProgrammer Well, the user is supposed to interact with it (if they so choose). An example of this use would be if their keyboard is broken.

Comment: Sorry, I mean via the keyboard

Comment: @MadProgrammer The keyboard should also still be an optional input tho (depending on which ever the user feels like using). Like the "Calculator" program on Windows7 works.

Comment: Yep, that's my idea.  Basically, the current text field can still receive key events as per it's normal operation, but with the buttons set to be unfocusable, the current text field will never lose focus, meaning the user can mix inputs (mouse clicks on the button or by typing on the keyboard)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I see now, I didn't know what you meant before. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't "expect" the user to use the keyboard to navigate the buttons, then I would simply make them unfocusable.  This way, the user can click the button, but the currently active field will not lose focus.  The user can either type directly into the field or click the numpad...

[image]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Component;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;

public class TestNumPad {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestNumPad();
    }

    public TestNumPad() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            JTextField field = new JTextField(10);
            add(field, gbc);
            add(new NumPad(), gbc);
            field.requestFocusInWindow();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }
    }

    public class NumPad extends JPanel {

        private ActionHandler actionHandler;

        public NumPad() {
            setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 3));
            actionHandler = new ActionHandler();
            for (int index = 1; index < 10; index++) {
                add(createButton(index));
            }
            add(new JPanel());
            add(createButton(0));
            add(new JPanel());
        }

        protected JButton createButton(int index) {
            JButton btn = new JButton(String.valueOf(index));
            btn.setFocusable(false);
            btn.addActionListener(actionHandler);
            return btn;
        }

        public class ActionHandler implements ActionListener {

            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                Object source = e.getSource();
                if (source instanceof JButton) {
                    JButton btn = (JButton) source;
                    try {
                        int value = Integer.parseInt(btn.getText().trim());
                        Component comp = KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().getFocusOwner();
                        if (comp instanceof JTextComponent) {
                            JTextComponent tc = (JTextComponent) comp;
                            tc.setText(tc.getText() + value);
                        }
                    } catch (Exception exp) {
                        exp.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It's a nice way to "fake" it ;)

Answer (score 2):

The essence of what you need to do is to:
1. create a method that appends a number onto the end of the textbox
2. add a Event Listener to each button that calls that method passing the value of the current button to the method.

For Example:

```
// Method to Append Number to Textbox
public void addNumberToTextBox(int currentVal) {
     txtOutputBox.Value = txtOutputBox.Value + currentVal
} 

// Initialize Some Buttons 
JButton btnOne = new JButton("1");
JButton btnTwo = new JButton("2");
JButton btnThree = new JButton("3");

// Add an ActionListener to the buttons
ButtonHandler handler = new ButtonHandler();
btnOne.addActionListener(handler);
btnTwo.addActionListener(handler);
btnThree.addActionListener(handler);

// Class to deal with when a button is pressed
private class ButtonHandler implements ActionListener {
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      // Converst the number to int
      int num = Integer.parseInt(e.getSource().Value);
      // Call the method
      addNumberToTextBox(num);                     
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> I have no clue how to use the code I found

You create a button from the Action and then add the button to your GUI. For example:

```
JButton one = new JButton( new AddDigit("1") );
```

The code will add the text to the last text field that had focus.

Answer (score 0):

Check out this demo code. It will display a basic text field and a text area where the **text field is editable** and the **text area is not editable**.

When the user presses Enter in the text field, the program copies the text field's contents to the text area, and then selects all the text in the text field.

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class TextDemo extends JPanel implements ActionListener {
    protected JTextField textField;
    protected JTextArea textArea;
    private final static String newline = "\n";

    public TextDemo() {
        super(new GridBagLayout());

        textField = new JTextField(20);
        textField.addActionListener(this);

        textArea = new JTextArea(5, 20);
        textArea.setEditable(false);
        JScrollPane scrollPane = new JScrollPane(textArea);

        //Add Components to this panel.
        GridBagConstraints c = new GridBagConstraints();
        c.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;
        add(textField, c);

        c.fill = GridBagConstraints.BOTH;
        c.weightx = 1.0;
        c.weighty = 1.0;
        add(scrollPane, c);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent evt) {
        String text = textField.getText();
        textArea.append(text + newline);
        textField.selectAll();

        //Make sure the new text is visible, even if there
        //was a selection in the text area.
        textArea.setCaretPosition(textArea.getDocument().getLength());
    }

    /**
     * Create the GUI and show it.  For thread safety,
     * this method should be invoked from the
     * event dispatch thread.
     */
    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        //Create and set up the window.
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("TextDemo");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        //Add contents to the window.
        frame.add(new TextDemo());

        //Display the window.
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Schedule a job for the event dispatch thread:
        //creating and showing this application's GUI.
        javax.swing.SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
```

Check out to learn more about JFrame Buttons and Text Fields: https://javatutorial.net/jframe-buttons-listeners-text-fields