# if i press a button, the text from the button to appear on my text area

Tags: java, user-interface, actionlistener, calculator

I started to make a Java Calculator with GUI but i have a problem. I am new with Java and i am sorry if my question is stupid. I want to know how i can correctly write the code for the Action Listener so that i can press a button and the text writen on that button to appear on a text area. Everything commented is what i was trying to do but didn't work.

```
package calculator;
import java.awt.Label;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;

import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class GUI extends JFrame {
    JButton Radical;
    JButton ImpartireLa1;
    JButton Inmultire;
    JButton Impartire;
    JButton Scadere;
    JButton Adunare;
    JButton Egal;
    JButton Zero;
    JButton Sapte;
    JButton Opt;
    JButton Noua;
    JButton Sase;
    JButton Cinci;
    JButton Patru;
    JButton Trei;
    JButton Doi;
    JButton Unu;
    StringBuilder tex;
    JTextField display;
    JLabel lol;

    GUI (){
        setTitle("Calculator");
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setSize(1400,800);

        this.setLayout(null);

        Radical = new JButton("rad");
        Radical.setBounds(100,100,60,60);

        ImpartireLa1= new JButton("1/x");
        ImpartireLa1.setBounds(200,100,60,60);

        Inmultire= new JButton("*");
        Inmultire.setBounds(300,100,60,60);

        Impartire= new JButton("/");
        Impartire.setBounds(400,100,60,60);

        Scadere= new JButton("-");
        Scadere.setBounds(500,100,60,60);

        Adunare= new JButton("+");
        Adunare.setBounds(500,200,60,60);

        Egal= new JButton("=");
        Egal.setBounds(500,300,60,60);

        Sapte= new JButton("7");
        Sapte.setBounds(100,200,80,80);

        Opt= new JButton("8");
        Opt.setBounds(230,200,80,80);

        Noua= new JButton("9");
        Noua.setBounds(360,200,80,80);

        Patru= new JButton("4");
        Patru.setBounds(100,300,80,80);

        Cinci= new JButton("5");
        Cinci.setBounds(230,300,80,80);

        Sase= new JButton("6");
        Sase.setBounds(360,300,80,80);

        Unu= new JButton("1");
        Unu.setBounds(100,400,80,80);

        Doi= new JButton("2");
        Doi.setBounds(230,400,80,80);

        Trei= new JButton("3");
        Trei.setBounds(360,400,80,80);

        Zero= new JButton("0");
        Zero.setBounds(480,400,80,80);

        this.setLayout(null);

        display= new JTextField();
        display.setBounds(100,10, 465, 45);



 add(Trei); add(Doi);add(Unu);add(Patru);add(Cinci);        add(Sase);add(Sapte);add(Opt);add(Noua);add(Radical);add(ImpartireLa1);add(Inmultire); add(Impartire);add(Adunare);add(Scadere);add(Egal); add(Zero);add(display);setVisible(true);


        class Patru implements ActionListener {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                //String s= text.getText()+ Patru.getText();
                //text.setText(s);
                     /// text.setText( getText(4) );

                /*JButton Patru = (JButton)e.getSource();
                if(Patru.getText().equals("4"))
                    display.setText("");
                lol.setVisible(true); */

                /*if(e.getSource() == Patru)
                {
                    String s = "4";
                    display.setText(s);

                }*/

                /* JButton Patru = (JButton)e.getSource();
                    String text = Patru.getText();
                    Object tex;
                    if (text.equals("4")) {
                        doMath math = new doMath();
                        int result = math.doMath1(tex.toString());
                       tex = new StringBuilder(32);

                    } else {
                        ((StringBuilder) tex).append(text);
            }*/
            /*  String text = "4";
                if(e.getSource() == Patru)
                {
                    text += "4";
                    display.setText(text);
                }
            }*/
}
            }
    class Cinci implements ActionListener{

        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }

        public void ActionPerformed(ActionEvent e1)
        {
            String s1= display.getText()+ Cinci.getText();
            display.setText(s1);
        }

    }
    }



    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
            GUI Calculator= new GUI();  
    }
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Add text to two textfields with JButtons](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763695/add-text-to-two-textfields-with-jbuttons)

Comment: `display.setText(((JButton)e.getSource()).getText())`  (or append) in actionListener

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to this is fairly simple:

- The text in a JButton can be set with `button.setText("sometext")` and that same text can be aquired by using `String content = button.getText()`.
- To use a ActionListener you can add the interface to your JFrame that looks like this: `public class GUI extends JFrame implements ActionListener {` you just have to add implements ActionListener to your existing line.
- Now you need to add the ActionListener to your button with `button.addActionListener(this)` Note: It is important that you add the Action Listener right after you created the new Button object.
- The last thing you need to do is to tell the ActionListener what he should do when the button get´s clicked. So you need to create a method in your GUI class:

  @Override

  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

  textfield.setText(button.getText());

  }

And thats basically all you need to change the Text in a JTextField when you click a button.

Answer (score 0):

**First:** define your `ActionListener` classes **outside** of your constructor method.

**Second:** add an instance of your `ActionListener` to each of your `JButtons`

```
Radical.addActionListener(new Patru());
```

**Third:** implement the `actionPerformed` method like this:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    JButton src = (JButton)e.getSource();
    display.setText(src.getText());
}
```