# How to add a JButton value to a JTextField selected?

Tags: java, swing

I'm learning JAVA GUI

How Can I add a value from my JButton(1,2,3,[...]) to a specific JTextField with click?

**Example:**

**First>** Click to JTextField[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u54TR.png)

**2nd>** click on JButton 3

How can I add value JButton 3 to my JTextField selected?

I know how to put a JButton value in a single JTextField, but I don't know how to do it in several different JTextField

*I saw some related posts, but I can't implement them in my code, maybe because I don't understand English very well and I can end up confusing some things*

I'm trying this:

```
 package jamilzin.magicsquare;
    import javax.swing.*;
     import java.awt.*;
     import java.awt.event.*;



public class MagicSquare implements ActionListener {

    //declarando
    JFrame frame;
    JPanel panel,panelFunctions;
    JButton[] numbers = new JButton[10];
    JTextField[] positions = new JTextField[9];
    JButton[] functions = new JButton[2];
    
    
    void magicSquare(){
    
    frame = new JFrame("Quadrado Magico");
    frame.setSize(500,500);
    panel = new JPanel();
    panelFunctions = new JPanel();
    
     numbers[1] = new JButton("1");
     numbers[2] = new JButton("2");
     numbers[3] = new JButton("3");
     numbers[4] = new JButton("4");
     numbers[5] = new JButton("5");
     numbers[6] = new JButton("6");
     numbers[7] = new JButton("7");
     numbers[8] = new JButton("8");
     numbers[9] = new JButton("9");
     
     functions[0]= new JButton("Limpar");
     functions[1]= new JButton("Sair");
     
     
    for(int i=1;i<10;i++){
     numbers[i].addActionListener(this);
     numbers[i].setBackground(Color.lightGray);
    }
    
    for(int i=0; i<9;i++){
    positions[i] = new JTextField();
positions[i].addActionListener(this);
}
 


    panel.setBounds(0, 0, 500, 400);
   panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(6,3,0,0));
    panelFunctions.setBounds(50,410,400,30);
   panelFunctions.setLayout(new GridLayout(1,2,250,0));
   
    panel.add(positions[0]);
    panel.add(positions[1]);
    panel.add(positions[2]);
    panel.add(positions[3]);
    panel.add(positions[4]);
    panel.add(positions[5]);
    panel.add(positions[6]);
    panel.add(positions[7]);
    panel.add(positions[8]);
    panel.add(numbers[1]);
    panel.add(numbers[2]);
    panel.add(numbers[3]);
    panel.add(numbers[4]);
    panel.add(numbers[5]);
    panel.add(numbers[6]);
    panel.add(numbers[7]);
    panel.add(numbers[8]);
    panel.add(numbers[9]);
    panelFunctions.add(functions[0]);
    panelFunctions.add(functions[1]);
    frame.setLayout(null);

  
    frame.setVisible(true);
      frame.add(panel);
    frame.add(panelFunctions);
    }
    
    
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

   if(e.getSource()==positions[1]){
       positions[1].setText("5");
   //    positions[1].setText(e.getActionCommand());

   }
 
    }

       public static void main(String[] args) {
        MagicSquare quadrado = new MagicSquare();
        quadrado.magicSquare();
    }


    
    
}
```

[its my GUI](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u54TR.png)

Comment: In my tests, the "best" try was when click on number 2, set a JTextField 2 value 2, click on 3 set JText 3 value 3... but i dont know how to click in JTextField 6 and set a value 3 as example

Comment: Create a class variable that stores a JTextField like so `public JTextField selected;`, then create an event on all the text fields that updates a class variable like so `selected = (JTextField)e.getSource();` and finally yo can change your JButtons to all use the same actiorPerformed event like so `selected.setText(((JButton)e.getSource()).getText());`

Comment: thank you @sorifiend tomorrow when I wake up, i'll start my tests again. good night

Comment: If you want this functionality for all text components on the frame then use a custom `TextAction`. The TextAction already provided support to determine the last text component that had focus. Check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763695/add-text-to-two-textfields-with-jbuttons/8765347#8765347 for such a class.

Answer (score 3):

You'll want to have a look at [How to Write a Focus Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/focuslistener.html)

Basically, you need to attach a `FocusListener` to each text field.  When a text field gains focus, you will want to set a property to the instance of the `JTextField` which gained focus.  When you tap a button, you use this property to set the text (assumming it's not `null`)

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.FocusAdapter;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import java.awt.event.FocusListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {
        private JTextField[] positions = new JTextField[9];
        private JButton[] numbers = new JButton[10];

        private JTextField lastFocusedField;

        public TestPane() {
            JPanel textFieldPane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 3));

            FocusListener focusListener = new FocusAdapter() {
                @Override
                public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
                    lastFocusedField = (JTextField) e.getSource();
                }
            };

            for (int index = 0; index < positions.length; index++) {
                positions[index] = new JTextField(10);
                positions[index].addFocusListener(focusListener);
                textFieldPane.add(positions[index]);
            }

            ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (lastFocusedField != null) {
                        lastFocusedField.setText(e.getActionCommand());
                    }
                }
            };

            JPanel buttonGridPane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 3));
            for (int index = 0; index < numbers.length; index++) {
                numbers[index] = new JButton(Integer.toString(index));
                numbers[index].addActionListener(actionListener);
            }
            for (int index = 0; index < 9; index++) {
                buttonGridPane.add(numbers[index]);
            }
            JPanel numbersPane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1));
            numbersPane.add(buttonGridPane);
            numbersPane.add(numbers[9]);

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

            add(textFieldPane, gbc);
            add(numbersPane, gbc);
        }
    }
}
```

Now, you need to make some decisions, when you tap a button should you reset the "last focused text field" or not.  Because otherwise, you can keep tapping buttons and the last focused text field will keep updating.

## A "cat" problem...

Which means there's more then one way to solve it.  The original answer, to use `FocusListener`, was used because it was "simple" and easy for a new developer to implement, and doesn't require an in deepth knowledge of how the inner workings of the Swing API works.

### `KeyboardFocusManager`

This is a little more heavy handed, as it will notify you of when ANY component becomes focused, so you need to make the effort to isolate those components you are interested in.

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.KeyboardFocusManager;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {
        private JTextField[] positions = new JTextField[9];
        private JButton[] numbers = new JButton[10];

        private JTextField lastFocusedField;

        public TestPane() {
            JPanel textFieldPane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 3));

            KeyboardFocusManager.getCurrentKeyboardFocusManager().addPropertyChangeListener(new PropertyChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                    Object newValue = evt.getNewValue();
                    if (newValue instanceof JTextField) {
                        JTextField textField = (JTextField) newValue;
                        // If there are other text fields in the view, we need
                        // to ignore them
                        if (isOfInterest(textField)) {
                            lastFocusedField = textField;
                        } else {
                            lastFocusedField = null;
                        }
                    }
                }

                protected boolean isOfInterest(JTextField field) {
                    for (JTextField other : positions) {
                        if (field == other) {
                            return true;
                        }
                    }
                    return false;
                }
            });

            for (int index = 0; index < positions.length; index++) {
                positions[index] = new JTextField(10);
                textFieldPane.add(positions[index]);
            }

            ActionListener actionListener = new ActionListener() {
                @Override
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                    if (lastFocusedField != null) {
                        lastFocusedField.setText(e.getActionCommand());
                    }
                }
            };

            JPanel buttonGridPane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 3));
            for (int index = 0; index < numbers.length; index++) {
                numbers[index] = new JButton(Integer.toString(index));
                numbers[index].addActionListener(actionListener);
            }
            for (int index = 0; index < 9; index++) {
                buttonGridPane.add(numbers[index]);
            }
            JPanel numbersPane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1));
            numbersPane.add(buttonGridPane);
            numbersPane.add(numbers[9]);

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

            add(textFieldPane, gbc);
            add(numbersPane, gbc);
        }
    }
}
```

### `TextAction`

As pointed out by [camickr](https://stackoverflow.com/users/131872/camickr), you could also make use of a `TextAction`, as demonstrated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763695/add-text-to-two-textfields-with-jbuttons/8765347#8765347).

See [How to Use Actions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/action.html) for more details

```
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextField;
import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;
import javax.swing.text.TextAction;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Main();
    }

    public Main() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                JFrame frame = new JFrame();
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {
        private JTextField[] positions = new JTextField[9];
        private JButton[] numbers = new JButton[10];

        private JTextField lastFocusedField;

        public TestPane() {
            JPanel textFieldPane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 3));

            for (int index = 0; index < positions.length; index++) {
                positions[index] = new JTextField(10);
                textFieldPane.add(positions[index]);
            }

            JPanel buttonGridPane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 3));
            for (int index = 0; index < numbers.length; index++) {
                numbers[index] = new JButton(new NumberAction(Integer.toString(index)));
            }
            for (int index = 0; index < 9; index++) {
                buttonGridPane.add(numbers[index]);
            }
            JPanel numbersPane = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1));
            numbersPane.add(buttonGridPane);
            numbersPane.add(numbers[9]);

            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;

            add(textFieldPane, gbc);
            add(numbersPane, gbc);
        }

        protected class NumberAction extends TextAction {
            private String value;

            public NumberAction(String value) {
                super(value);
                setName(value);
                this.value = value;
            }

            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                JTextComponent component = getFocusedComponent();
                component.replaceSelection(value);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you @MadProgrammer tomorrow when I wake up, i'll start my tests again. good night

Comment: don't extend for configuration reasons <g> On a more serious note: wondering why you add individual listeners - wouldn't a single hook into the focusOwner property of the keyboardFocusManager be a more modern variant?

Comment: Because I'm lazy ;)

Comment: The `TextAction` class supports this functionality by default. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8763695/add-text-to-two-textfields-with-jbuttons/8765347#8765347. Of course it will only work if your logic is the same for all text components on the frame. Not sure if you are not aware of this class or you and @kleopatra don't like using it (because of the above limitation)?

Comment: @camickr no dislike just swingish rust :)

Comment: initial lazyness leads to .. <g> a little nit: no need for the actionListener (nor the lastFocused field) in the example with the TextAction. Actually, using the TextAction is __the__ solution to the problem, IMO, you might consider putting it as first option *ducking.

Comment: @kleopatra This is what happens when you copy and paste the code 

Answer (score 0):

```
    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
      JButton btnPressed = (JButton)e.getSource();
      for(int i=0; i<numbers.length;i++){
        if(numbers[i] == btnPressed){
            positions[i-1].setText(btnPressed.getText());
        }
     }

    }
```

Comment: this dont work, i dont want complete my array with  sequency1 2 3 4...  i want  select JTextField[4] and put number[9] example

Comment: Yes but I have give an idea that how can you get the text from button and set into the relevant button..
you can do this as well if you don't want to iterate array.
`positions[Integer.parseInt(btnPressed.getText())-1].setText(btnPressed.getText());`